# Leaflet: Image Overlay projected incorrectly

Tags: leaflet, raster, qgis

in leaflet I added an image to my map (image overlay).
The image is a georeferenced jpeg, and it's a raster generated by Qgis.
In leaflet I setted the image bound points correctly (NE and SW), and I tested this even after the map is rendered.
So, if the **extreme points (NE and SW) are corrects**, the internal image points do not correspond to the real coordinates, as you can see in the image (see the detail of railway tracks):
[image: overlay.png]

Any clue?

Comment: You might reach a more appropriate audience on [Geographic Information Systems SE](https://gis.stackexchange.com/) for this type of question.

Comment: Duplicate of https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/210597/image-overlay-qgis-raster-projected-incorrectly-on-leaflet-js